# Angular JS data not binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The code below is angular js with bootstrap. The problem is that when I render this code in plnkr it works fine and in my project it misbehaves. Both the snapshots are shown below. I am not aware of debugging tools available to debug such a angular specific behaviour.

The variable $scope.radioModel never gets the value inside my controller.

Also its a complex controller otherwise and all the data binding so far.

HTML

```
<h4>Simple example</h4>
<pre>radioModel: {{radioModel || 'null'}}</pre>
<pre>anotherRadioModel: {{anotherRadioModel || 'null'}}</pre>
<div class="btn-group" ng-click="onButtonClick()" >
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Left</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Right'">Right</label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.onButtonClick = function(){
  $scope.anotherRadioModel = $scope.radioModel;
} ;
```

Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/xOP4zzXYBCmHq6TzFkf4?p=preview

Snapshot 1 plnkr: 
[image: On Plunker]

Snapshot 2 localhost: 
[image]

Comment: use `controller as` syntax, you have ng-model without dot, this is cause of the issue for most angularjs newbees

Comment: F12 in chrome or dev tools in any browser, see if you get any errors.

Comment: @harish the project is scaffolded using Yeoman.  So I feel the module controller syntax would be correct

Comment: @mohammad sorry for not mentioning this but no errors in dev console

Comment: no, whatever scaffolding you use, its you who has to use controller as syntax in html... may be change the scaffold html if its not already using `controller as`

Comment: @harish can you make the edit in the plnkr shared to help me understand better.